# Symfony 2 and sencha extjs 5/6

Tags: symfony, extjs6-modern

I got an app on Symfony 2 with Extjs 4 that I want to update to be responsive.

I have grids, forms, actions on grid, ... mixed in Twig and ExtJs (twig make the nav bar and autorizations and Ext present datas) based on this **zazencode.com/symfony/2014/02/04/extjs-with-symfony-part1.html**, and it works fine.

I'd like to have a full front responsive with extJs 6 modern consumming REST with Symfony.

I tried to load Ext 6 app with Symfony but I failed to play it.

I tried those solutions but without success too :

- https://github.com/partkeepr/extjs6
- https://www.teqneers.de/2015/09/sencha-ext-js-meets-symfony/ (nearly works)
- www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?288955-Extjs5-with-Symfony2-Folder-structure, doesn't work too (just blank page with Symfony Bar OK 200)

Is there a way to use Ext app 5 or 6 with Symfony ?

Thank's for help

Comment: My sencha app is in the web folder of Symfony, in js/packages/my-app. and I request it via Twig with the code code made by sencha `Ext.beforeLoad = function (tags) {
            var s = location.search,  // the query string (ex "?foo=1&bar")
                profile;` and `<script id="microloader" data-app="<senche-hash>" type="text/javascript" src="js/packages/my-app/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I find an answer, or a begin, in the article : http://thebigbrainscompany.com/blog/posts/intgration-grunt-et-bower-au-sein-d-une-application-symfony.

I think it's a good way, but in the meantime, I choice to pass to Twig + jQuery + Bootstrp to do the job.